# f# sum after last negative number

Tags: list, f#, sum

Hello i have to make exercise with list. I had one with checking arithmetic with lists code :

```
let rec q3 lista r = 
match lista with 
| [] -> false
| [x] -> true
| x1::x2::xs -> if r = x2 - x1 then (q3 xs r) else false


q3 [2;4;6] 2;;
```

But after this excersize i have problem. I have to calculate sum for numbers in list after last negative number
or for all if i have only positive numbers in my list.

this is code for sum . This is pretty easy but how do make this :( I am quite new in f# programming :P  Any reflections ?

I have list for exmaple like this :

```
let lists = [4;-3;1;9]

// sum =10   

//calculate 
    let rec sum values = 
    match values with
    | [] -> 0
   | head::tail -> head + sum(tail)

//test
let x = sum lists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're learning F# and so I'm not going to show the full answer (then you wouldn't learn much).

You want to sum all numbers in a list after the last negative number. Another way to look at this is that you want to restart the counting (to start from zero again) every time you find a negative number as you are walking over the list.

This is not easy to do with your version of `sum`, but you can rewrite the `sum` function to use the accumulator argument (which keeps the sum of numbers so far):

```
let rec sumAcc acc values = 
  match values with
  | [] -> 
      // return the sum of values in the list so far
  | head::tail -> 
      // add the value in the 'head' to the sum so far
      // and call 'sumAcc' recursively on the rest of the list

let sum values = sumAcc 0 values
```

Now, you can solve the problem quite easily - because when `head` is negative, you can just reset the "sum so far" in the accumulator argument. So, you just need to add another case looking like:

```
 | head::tail when head < 0 ->
      // Ignore the sum so far and call 'sumAcc' on the rest of the list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let rec sumList acc lst =
     match lst with
     | [] -> acc
     | hd::tl -> hd + sumList acc tl  
     |hd::tl when hd < 0 -> sumList acc lst

 let sum lst = sumList 0 lst ;;

  sum [1;2;-5] ;;
```

Dont know how to do this   //'sumAcc' recursively on the rest of the list
sumList acc lst is rather wrong :D because still get -2 value :D

Comment: Hint: Its all about the accumulator. 
You need to add to the accumulator or 0 it out.